# Creating an array of iterated values

Tags: julia

I have read through a lot of julia-posts, but haven't found anything concerning this very special problem.
We are iterating eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors via Power-Iteration.
The algorithm is working and calculating the approximate eigenvalue, but we are asked to save the values of our approximate  values after each iteration in a seperate vector.

I tried:

1. collect(lambda_k)
2. in a while loop:
   l_end = []
   push!(l_end,lambda_k)

But it doesn't work, are you able to help me?

Greetings!
Mass_Matics

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What are you expecting this code to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: Helping minimal working example would help a lot. How soes the `lambda_k` look like and how does `l_end` look like? 
You should have defined array before you start pushing to it.